# Post Apocalyptic show in the desert with a vehicle named the “Green Monster”

Tags: story-identification, tv, post-apocalyptic

I remember seeing it on network TV in the early to mid '80s. Post-apocalyptic world. The scene I recall is two men driving down a desert highway in a vehicle with “Green Monster” painted on the side. One guy explains to the other that is was named after the Green Monster wall in Fenway baseball park in Boston. The front of the vehicle could split down the middle with separate cockpits. Looked like a dune racer, perhaps with desert camo. The guys may have been cops or a security force protecting water shipments in a water war, but I could be mixing shows with that memory. Anyone know what show this was?

Answer (score 11):

This is ***[Badlands 2005](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469026/)*** (1988). [It was apparently a failed pilot](http://www.criticallyacclaimed.net/2019/08/canceled-too-soon-159-badlands-2005-1988.html) for a TV series which was ultimately never commissioned.

From IMDB:

> In this unsold post-apocalyptic TV pilot, a U.S. marshal and his by-the-book cyborg partner are tasked to escort two mail order brides to a remote desert area where their husbands work, but a local bandit leader has other plans for them.

It features a *Mad Max*-style, post-apocalyptic setting and a vehicle matching your description. There's a good shot of the vehicle at around the [3:56](https://youtu.be/ndGkKlBa3bw?t=236) mark in the video below, and the following conversation occurs at around the [21:43](https://youtu.be/ndGkKlBa3bw?t=1303) mark.

> SARAH GWYNNE: It's amazing.
>
> MARSHAL GARSON MACBETH: What?
>
> SARAH GWYNNE: This machine. But I'm curious about one thing. **How come you call it the Green Monster?**
>
> MARSHAL GARSON MACBETH: **You ever hear of a place called Fenway Park?**
>
> SARAH GWYNNE: All I know is recreational zone number three back in Los Angeles.
>
> MARSHAL GARSON MACBETH: **Fenway Park is... was... a baseball stadium in Boston.** And unlike the domes that they built in the seventies and the eighties, Fenway had character; it had nooks and crannies everywhere. It had individuality.
>
> SARAH GWYNNE: That's when they played baseball outside.
>
> MARSHAL GARSON MACBETH: Yeah. **The Green Monster was the name of the wall in left field.** It was real close, and yet it was thirty-seven feet high and had a twenty-three-foot screen on top of it. It was tantalizing to the batters and a challenge to the left-fielders who had to learn how to play it. I guess I just liked the name.
>
> SARAH GWYNNE: And the individuality it represents.

Comment: "Is that Sharon Stone?"  [Checks.]  "Yep, that's Sharon Stone.  That would have been different."

Comment: Confusingly it seem to have been directed by _a_ George Miller, but not the Mad Max one